# How to unroot Motorola Moto G 2014?

Tags: unrooting, motorola-moto-g2

I have rooted my Motorola Moto G 2014. But now, I want to unroot it to get Lollipop update. I followed  few suggestions, but in all of them stock Android download link is not working.

And, can I get the Android L update prompt even if my phone is rooted?

Comment: i'm not sure, but I think you'll get it anyways. Also, I'd say that some developers find L very hard to root, so I'd leave it rooted and wait for a stock-L-based custom ROM

Answer (score 1):

You can go to SuperSu app or any other Superuser app you are using, and go to Settings and you will see a Full unroot option, press that and restart the phone when prompted. This should unroot the phone. But the boot loader will stay unlocked if you have unlocked it.

Comment: Thanks buddy, I think i have unrooted the device some how nut now i need to relock the bootloader can you help ?

Comment: go here http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2537119 its an extensive guide for unlocked moto g , but its for 2013 edition but you will get an idea from it anyway, its a general method. On the page , press ctrl+f and type relock.

Comment: and I think you should go to http://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-g-2014 here is a community of people with moto g 2014's , hope this helps , and yeah vote up my answer please if it helped.

Comment: this will help you too http://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-g-2014/general/index-start-t2894742